# CDbl() woes and type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I'm fairly new to VBA and have had some issues with a script I've been tasked to write. What it's supposed to do is to use the semicolon-spaced data in a single cell (the data contains names and numbers inside brackets) and find the names with the biggest numbers then separate that into different cells.

To take out the numbers from string I'm using the custom function ExtractNumber developed by ozgrid: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExtractNum.htm

I keep getting

> error 424

while trying to call that function, precisely in its last line:

```
ExtractNumber = CDbl(lNum)
```

Like another user suggested, I tried switching the type of variable here:

```
ExtractNumber(rCell As String,
```

but it has not helped at all. I've also tried switching the CDbl() command to any other C...() type command as well as removing it entirely. No luck. I feel like I'm hitting an enormous brick wall, and my time is slowly running out. Could I ask for assistance once more? Here is my full code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Divide()

Dim txt As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim Full As Variant
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim stored() As Integer

txt = (CStr(ActiveCell.Value))
Full = Split(txt, ";")
a = UBound(Full)
b = a - 1

ReDim stored(b)

For i = 0 To a
    stored(i) = ExtractNumber((Full(i)))
Next i

Dim primary_index As Integer
Dim primary_no As Integer
Dim primary_name As String
primary_index = Application.Match(Application.Max(stored), stored, 0)
primary_no = stored(primary_index)
primary_name = Full(primary_index)
stored(primary_index) = 0

If UBound(stored) > 1 Then
    Dim secondary_index As Integer
    Dim secondary_no As Integer
    Dim secondary_name As String
    secondary_index = Application.Match(Application.Max(stored), stored, 0)
    secondary_no = stored(secondary_index)
    secondary_name = Full(secondary_index)
End If

For i = 0 To 6
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert
Next i

If UBound(stored) > 2 Then
    Dim names() As String
    ReDim names(0 To a)
    For j = 0 To a
        If Not (j = primary_index Or j = secondary_index) Then
            names(j) = Full(j)
        End If
    Next j

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = primary_name
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = primary_no
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = secondary_name
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = secondary_no
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = names
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value - primary_no             - secondary_no)

ElseIf UBound(stored) = 2 Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = primary_name
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = primary_no
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = secondary_name
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = secondary_no
End

Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = primary_name
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = primary_no
End

End If
End Sub
```

Here's a sample of my data: [click](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m4gNqfaU8Z1kbPI3kE35Q7wPxhmZfgNF/view?usp=sharing)

Example of a cells content:  `A&W All American Food (1) ; American Pie Cafe (1) ; Arby's (53) ; Auntie Anne's (13) ; Auntie Anne's Hand-Rolled Soft Pretzels (1) ; Baskin Robbins (1) ; Beef-A-Roo (1) ; Big Steer Restaurant ; Bill Ellis BBQ (1) ; Breakfast/Soup Bar (116) ; Broadway Diner (4) ; Burger King (4) ; Chester's Chicken (2) ; Cinnabon (126) ; Country Market (1) ; Country Skillet (1) ; Cuban Cuisine Restaurant (1) ; Dairy Queen (23) ; Dan's Big Slice Pizza (1) ; Day Breaker's Cafe (1) ; Deli (17) ; Denny's (97) ; Dunkin' Donuts (6) ; Family Restaurant (1) ; Full Service (4) ; Golden Corral (2) ; Gooseberry Farms (1) ; GrandMa Max's (3) ; Hardee's (1) ; Hot Food and Pizza (44) ; Hot Stuff Pizza (3) ; Huddle House (1) ; IHOP Restaurant (1) ; J's Wok and Grill (1) ; Johnny Pastrami (1) ; Junie's Restaurant (1) ; KFC (3) ; Krispy Krunchy Chicken (1) ; Long John Silver's (1) ; Max's Highway Diner (1) ; McDonald's (39) ; Mexican Grill (1) ; Milestone Diner (3) ; Moe's Southwest Grill (6) ; Nathan's Famous (1) ; Noble Roman's Pizza (1) ; Penn 80 Grill (1) ; Pizza Hut (4) ; Pizza Shop (1) ; Q Eats (1) ; Quiznos (2) ; Sam Bass Steakhouse (1) ; Sbarro (1) ; Silver Skillet (1) ; Subway (231) ; Sunshine Cafe (1) ; Taco Bell (8) ; Taco Bell/KFC (1) ; Taco John's (1) ; Wendy's Old Fashioned Hamburgers (72)`

Comment: Need a sample of your data in order to reproduce your problem. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If your list is split into names with numbers in brackets (`Person1 (12); Person2 (10)`) then the `ExtractNumber` function is a bit verbose.  You just need to find the bracket.  If the whole name & number are in brackets (`(Person1 12); (Person2 10)`) then you could probably look for the space before the number.  So as Ron said - a sample of your data would help.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook  I've included a sample of my data, I hope it will be sufficient!

Comment: What does `names with the biggest numbers` mean?  All of the highest?  All of the two or three highest?  ???

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The two highest become a 'Primary brand' and 'Secondary brand' respectably, and have their amounts expressed in separate fields. The rest is put together in another field, called 'Other'.

Comment: _Big Steer Restaurant_ doesn't have a number after it - mistake, or do some not have numbers?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook not all have numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this could work.

The values are split and placed on a temporary worksheet for sorting.  An array sort within VBA is probably faster.

This considers the top two rows as the "Primary" and "Secondary" brands even if they have the same score.  All the other stores are just "others".

If a store doesn't have a number it's given a default number of 0.

```
Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz1")
        Divide .Range("G1:G7")
    End With

End Sub


Sub Divide(TextRange As Range)

    Dim rCell As Range, rCell1 As Range
    Dim vSplit As Variant
    Dim wrkShtTmp As Worksheet
    Dim sOthers As String

    'The parent of the range is the worksheet.
    'The parent of the worksheet is the workbook - we want to add a worksheet to the workbook.
    Set wrkShtTmp = TextRange.Parent.Parent.Worksheets.Add

    For Each rCell In TextRange
        With wrkShtTmp
            vSplit = Split(rCell, ";")
            'Place the values on the temporary sheet.
            .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(vSplit)) = Application.Transpose(vSplit)

            'Remove number & brackets from name.
            '=TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1)-1))
            .Range("B1").Resize(UBound(vSplit)).FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(RC[-1],FIND(""("",RC[-1])-1)),RC[-1])"

            'Place numbers in column C.
            '=IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),")","")),0)
            .Range("C1").Resize(UBound(vSplit)).FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(RC[-2],FIND(""("",RC[-2])+1,LEN(RC[-2])),"")"","""")),0)"

            With .Sort
                .SortFields.Clear
                .SortFields.Add Key:=wrkShtTmp.Range("C1").Resize(UBound(vSplit)), _
                    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .SetRange wrkShtTmp.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(vSplit), 3)
                .Header = xlNo
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With

            'Place the top two in columns 22 & 23 (V & W)
            TextRange.Parent.Cells(rCell.Row, 22) = .Cells(1, 2)
            TextRange.Parent.Cells(rCell.Row, 23) = .Cells(2, 2)

            'Stick all the other stores together in a string.
            For Each rCell1 In .Range("B3").Resize(UBound(vSplit) - 2)
                sOthers = sOthers & rCell1 & ", "
            Next rCell1
            sOthers = Left(sOthers, Len(sOthers) - 2)
            'Place the other stores in column 24 (X)
            TextRange.Parent.Cells(rCell.Row, 24) = sOthers

            'Clear the temporary sheet and Other stores string.
            .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(vSplit), 3).ClearContents
            sOthers = ""

        End With
    Next rCell

    'Delete the temporary sheet.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wrkShtTmp.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the problem is in the decimal separator that you are using for the floating point number.
Can you try like this:

```
ExtractNumber(change_commas(Full(i)))

Public Function change_commas(ByVal myValue As Variant) As String
   Dim str_temp as String
   str_temp = CStr(myValue)
   change_commas = Replace(str_temp, ",", ".")
End Function
```